# Import “nextcord” could not be resolved

Tags: nextcord

I have just installed nextcord, but when I try to import it to code it says: “Import “nextcord” could not be resolved” please help me.

Comment: You haven't specified any information about what you're doing - what programming language are you using? How did you install nextcord? What did you do to try and use nextcord? This is like asking "I turned on the switch and it didn't work", we can't help without any context at all.

Answer (score 0):

it is most likly that you haven't installed it yet. You can install it by running `pip instal -U nextcord`

Answer (score 0):

please check first if you have possibly multiple python installs (different versions / virtual envs) and possibly installed nextcord in the wrong version. If you are using an IDE you should have a list of the installed packages in your enviorment. If it is not showing in there you either have not installed it correctly or installed it for a different python instance.

Another problem might be that discord.py is still installed. This can lead to different problems as the standard nextcord install aliases the discord namespace. If this is the case uninstall both, discord.py and nextcord and then reinstall nextcord. If you want to keep discord.py there is a seperate setup script that does not alias the discord namespace or you should take a look at virtual enviroments